# Nine divisible by 9

Tags: logic, divisibility, summation

Given any seventeen integers, show that there is at least one subset of nine integers whose sum is divisible by $9$.

---

(one of my friend suggest me)
may be this theorem helpful

**Theorem**: Given any $2n-1$ integers, there is at least one subset of $n$ integers whose sum is divisible by $n$.

and also Fermat’s Little Theorem can be used

Comment: I have known some problems of this category handled well with the pigeon hole principle. Have you given it a try?

Comment: @ Aseem Dua may be....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a generalization](http://www.physics.harvard.edu/academics/undergrad/probweek/sol80.pdf) of the problem to which you are referring, namely the fact that given any $2n-1$ integers there exists a subset of $n$ integers divisible by $n$. Applying the theorem to the case of $n=9$ provides the desired result.